# TeamCity SSH to GitLab: Auth cancel

Tags: git, ssh, teamcity-9.0

I'm running TeamCity on Windows, running the service using a local user account TeamCity.

I'm trying to set up a Git VCS root to begin configuring a build.

So far, I've created a passwordless RSA key pair using ssh-keygen from within a git bash shell, saved to C:\Users\TeamCity.ssh\rsa_id and rsa_id.pub. Next I uploaded the public key to GitLab and successfully performed a git clone using the git bash shell - the key is accepted and the server key is added to the known hosts file.

Now, I've created a VCS root with the following settings:

- Type of VCS: Git
- VCS root name: Git Repository
- VCS root ID: Platform_GitRepository
- Fetch URL: git@dev.mycompany.org/mycompany/platform.git
- Default branch: refs/heads/master

For simplicity I have configured the authentication as follows:

- Authentication method: Custom Private Key
- Username: teamcity
- Private key path: C:\Users\TeamCity.ssh\id_rsa

I'd like to be able to use some of the alternative SSH key options, but I would like to get this to work in its simplest form first.

When pressing the Test Connection button, I get a very terse:

> List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel

I've looked in the teamcity-vcs.log file and can see the equivalent exception and stack trace:

```
[2016-04-07 14:53:24,470]   INFO [nio-8000-exec-1] -      jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Error occurred in test connection: jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.OperationContext.wrapException(OperationContext.java:177)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getRemoteRefs(GitVcsSupport.java:360)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getCurrentState(GitVcsSupport.java:139)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.TestConnectionCommand.checkFetchConnection(TestConnectionCommand.java:95)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.TestConnectionCommand.testConnection(TestConnectionCommand.java:68)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.testConnection(GitVcsSupport.java:265)
    at jetbrains.vcs.api.services.impl.TestConnectionServiceProvider$1.testConnection(TestConnectionServiceProvider.java:1)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.TestConnectionCommand.runTestConnection(TestConnectionCommand.java:27)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.TestConnectionCommand.doTestConnection(TestConnectionCommand.java:10)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.EditVcsRootsController.doPost(EditVcsRootsController.java:184)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseFormXmlController$1.handleRequest(BaseFormXmlController.java:53)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.AjaxRequestProcessor.processRequest(AjaxRequestProcessor.java:45)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseFormXmlController.doHandle(BaseFormXmlController.java:51)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseController.handleRequestInternal(BaseController.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.maintenance.TeamCityDispatcherServlet.service(TeamCityDispatcherServlet.java:3)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.DependencyParametersCalculationContextFilter.doFilter(DependencyParametersCalculationContextFilter.java:1)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.DisableSessionIdFromUrlFilter.doFilter(DisableSessionIdFromUrlFilter.java:6)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.diagnostic.web.DiagnosticFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.ResponseFragmentFilter.doFilter(ResponseFragmentFilter.java:16)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: teamcity@dev.surecloud.com:surecloud/platform.git: Auth cancel
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:161)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getRemoteRefs(GitVcsSupport.java:378)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getRemoteRefs(GitVcsSupport.java:355)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
    ... 58 more
```

There doesn't seem to be any more useful information available; I'm not sure how to proceed from here to diagnose why TeamCity isn't able to authenticate with the key specified.

I should also add that I've managed to get a connection to a GitHub account to work with the same key, so it would appear to be a specific combination of JSch and our GitLab server's setup.

Are there any logs available for JSch, or any verbosity switches I could enable? Any suggestions on steps I could take to progress this further?

Comment: Does the key have a passphrase?

Comment: The key does not include a passphrase.

Comment: May I ask if you got a solution for this back then? I'm experiencing the same issue now.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the username, and allow it to use the default "git" username. Alternatively, enter `git` into the username field.